# Inequality between $\sup |f^{(k)}(x)|$ for $k=0,1,2$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be twice differentiable  on an interval $I$. Let $M_k=\sup \limits_{x\in I} |f^{(k)}(x)|$ for $k=0,1,2$. Show that if $I=[-a,a]$, then $$|f'(x)|\leq \dfrac{M_0}{a}+\dfrac{x^2+a^2}{2a}M_2;$$

*Remark:* By interval I mean that $I$ could be open, closed or half-open interval.

After some attempts actually I was able to prove this inequality. My question is not about the solution but actually about the constants $M_k$. Note that if $I=[-a,a]$ then $M_0,M_1$ exist because $f$ and $f'$  are continuous functions. But it is possible that $M_2$ could be infinity, right?

Can anyone explain how to handle this case, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g(x) = x^2 \sin { 1\over x^2}$ for $x \in [-a,a]\setminus \{0\}$, and $g(0)=0$. Note that $g$ is differentiable and unbounded on $[-a,a]$. Let $f(x) = \int_0^x f(t)dt$. Then $M_0,M_1$ are finite but $M_2= \infty$.

The inequality is vacuously true in this case.